# ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of" ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10725, 3575]

Tags: python, valueerror, train-test-split

I have been stuck with this error for quite a while. Whenever I run this code, I get the following error:

```
raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10725, 3575]
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
n_classes = len(classes)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=0, test_size = 0.75)

X_train_scale = X_train/255.0
X_test_scale = X_test/255.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this error because **train_test_split** requires that X and Y must have the same length while it's not the case here. In fact :
`X.shape[0] == 10725` while `Y.shape[0] == 3575`

To solve this you have to reshape your X. Here is my suggestion:
`X.reshape(Y.shape[0], -1)`